# Getting unexpected characters written into a text file by a Java Program instead of an integer

Tags: java, file-io

I have a Java program for a two pass assembler for which I am currently doing pass two, during this I need to write an **Integer** into a file, but some unexpected characters are getting written into the file, I assure you the Value I am trying to write is definitely an integer, see below

```
Symbol Address : 231
Symbol Address : 237
Symbol Address : 237
Symbol Address : 236
Symbol Address : 210
Symbol Address : 210
Symbol Address : 236
Symbol Address : 236
```

The `Symbol Address` : `number`, this `number` is what I am trying to write into the file by the following code,

```
public String PassTwo() throws Exception{
        String source_inter_file  = "pass_one_output.txt";
        String object_file = "object_code.txt";
        FileReader file_rd = new FileReader(source_inter_file);
        BufferedReader buf_read = new BufferedReader(file_rd);
        FileWriter file_wrte = new FileWriter(object_file);
        BufferedWriter buf_wrte = new BufferedWriter(file_wrte);
        String CurrSourceLine = "";
        if(file_rd==null) return "Error : Passone output file not found";
        while((CurrSourceLine=buf_read.readLine())!=null){
            String token[] = CurrSourceLine.split("[ \t]+");
            if(token[0].length()==0){
                for(int i =0;i<3;i++){
                    file_wrte.write(" - ");
                }
                file_wrte.write('\n');
            }else{
               file_wrte.write(token[0]+" ");
               file_wrte.write(token[2]+" ");
               if(token.length==6 && token[4].equals("S")){
                System.out.println("Symbol Address : "+Symboltable[Integer.parseInt(token[5])].address);  
                file_wrte.write(Symboltable[Integer.parseInt(token[5])].address); // Error must be here 
               } 
               file_wrte.write('\n');
            }
        }
        file_wrte.close();
        file_rd.close();
        buf_read.close();
        return "Object code succesfully genrated";
    }
```

The characters written into the file are ç, í, Ò, instead of Symbol addresses. What am I doing wrong here.

```
 -  -  - 
200 1 ç
201 3 í
202 7 í
203 8 
204 7 
205 5 
206 5 
207 5 ì
208 4 
209 6 Ò
210 10 Ò
210 10 ì
231 0 
234 5 
235 1 ì
236 1 
237 0 
239 2
```

Comment: Show us the content of `Symboltable`.

Comment: @DorianGray My error has been solved, Onkar Ruikar, has the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `file_wrte.write(97);` it writes actual number to the file. When you open the file in text editor 97 is ACII value of character 'a'.

If you want to write 97 as a string to file then use  `file_wrte.write(String.valueOf(97));` This writes 57 55 to the file which in ASCII represents `97` string.

Try:
`file_wrte.write(String.valueOf(Symboltable[Integer.parseInt(token[5])].address));`

You are already doing similar thing here `file_wrte.write(token[0]+" ");`
Here the operator `+` is overloaded. 
 Compiler translates `String + object`  to `string.concat(object.toString())`.

Comment: It worked, can I ask you what was wrong with earlier approach, I am definitely missing a deeper detail in understanding Java File IO?

Comment: ```file_wrte.write(token[0]+" ");``` did not cause any problems, so why this one did?

Comment: Thanks for your time, I understood the problem.